# using highcharts with jhipster

Tags: highcharts, jhipster, yarnpkg

I'm trying to integrate highcharts to my jhipster Gateway using angular 4.
In the command line I used

```
>yarn add angular-highcharts@4
> yarn add --dev @types/highcharts@4
```

but i got this error :

```
./node_modules/angular-highcharts/angular-highcharts.es5.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'highcharts' in '/home/vagrant/IdeaProjects/chart/node_modules/angular-highcharts'
```

When I opened `./node_modules/angular-highchartsangular-highcharts.es5.js:`
I got:

```
this import is not supported by current javascriptversion
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import { Directive, ElementRef, Inject, Injectable, InjectionToken, Input, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
```

Am I missing a setting somewhere?

Comment: I suspect your problem is related to Highcharts with Webpack. Did you import into vendor.ts for webpack?

Comment: Doesn't look like an issue in Highcharts - more like a problem with unofficial Angular wrapper angular-highcharts. There's an official wrapper that haven't been reported to have this problem - https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular/ Have you tried this one?

Comment: U'r right Kacper Madej , i tried with the official and it works . thanks for your help.

Comment: Gaël Marziou ,  the problem is not in the importing but with the node module itself , i used  angular-highcharts and it works